# Find the possible values of and the probability mass function of X

Tags: probability-theory

Problem statement -

We flip a fair coin five times. For every heads you pay me 1 and for every tails I pay you 1. Let X denote my net winnings at the end of five flips. Find the possible values and the probability mass function of X.

My attempt -

I found that there are a total of 6 possible outcomes: 1, 3, 5, -1, -3, -5.

Next, I wanted to find to construct a probability mass function of X. In order to do this, I had to compute the probability of obtaining each net winning. So I had to compute 6 probabilities.

P(1 net gain) = (3!*2!/(5!), because 3 - 2 = 1, and there are 3! ways of arranging my wins across 5 "slots," and 2! ways of arranging my opponents losses, as well as a total of 5! ways of arranging all outcomes across 5 slots. Using this same logic for the other probabilities, I get:

P(1 net gain) = P(-1 net gain)

P(3 net gain) = 4!*1!/(5!) = P(-3 net gain)

P(5 net gain) = 1/(5!) = P(-5 net gain)

Adding all these probabilities up, I get

36/60

Which shows that something went wrong in my thought process, since all probabilities have to add up to 1 in a probability mass function.

**What did I do wrong? How do I do the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument that $X=1$ is produced by an arrangement of 3 wins and 2 losses is correct.

However, that should lead to you concluding that because there are $\binom 53$ ways to arrange three wins and two losses, and the probability for obtaining *each* such arrangement is $1/2^5$, therefore:- $$\mathsf P(X{=}1) ~=~ \dfrac{5!}{3!~2!}\cdot \dfrac 1{2^5}$$

Similarly for the other probabilities.

---

Also, it is relevant that the Binomial Theorem says: $2^5=\binom 50+\binom 51+\binom 52+\binom 53+\binom 54+\binom 55$ .